# three.js - How to keep objects linked when moving one of them?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to represent a graph with three.js, where nodes objects can be moved with click-and-drag.
My current problem is that the edges, created as THREE.Line going from one node to another, don't move with the node (edges should rotate / change length).

My code so far:

```
var colour = 0x568c4b, geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(size, size, size),
    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: colour }),
    position0 = new THREE.Vector3(-100, -60, 0),
    position1 = new THREE.Vector3(150, 50, 0);

node0 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
node0.position = position0;
scene.add(node0);
objects.push(node0);

node1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
node1.position = position1;
scene.add(node1);
objects.push(node1);

var edge_def = new THREE.Geometry();

/*
 * How to refresh this so that 'edge0' is always connected to 'node0' and 'node1'?
 */
edge_def.vertices.push(node0.position);
edge_def.vertices.push(node1.position);
/*
 */

edge_def.colors.push(new THREE.Color(colour));
edge_def.colors.push(new THREE.Color(colour));
edge0 = new THREE.Line(edge_def, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    linewidth: 5,
    vertexColors: true
}));
scene.add(edge0);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/La2NT/1) is a jsfiddle of what I have done (as I am currently learning how to use three.js, my code is heavily based on the draggable cubes (www.threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes) example from threejs.org). As you can see, dragging a node cube lets the edge unchanged when it should always be connected.

So if you could help by pointing me to resources or examples on how to do that, I would be very thankful.

EDIT: [This](http://oi60.tinypic.com/11w7dco.jpg) is what I try to do, with pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that THREE.JS caches almost everything for performance reasons. Including geometries. You have to tell the renderer that line geometry has changed by setting geometry's property **verticesNeedUpdate** to true.

I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxpmN/2/) code, so you should see it working now.

there is only one extra line of code needed in your onDocumentMouseMove function:

```
if (SELECTED) {
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
    SELECTED.position.copy(intersects[0].point.sub(offset));
    edge0.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true; //THIS WILL TELL RENDERER THAT GEOMETRY HAS CHANGED
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

(This is actually not aswering the original question, because I misunderstood it. But when I realized that, it was already marked as useful by 3 people, so I am keeping it here for people looking for answer of a little different question ;-)

If anybody wants to move all objects together as one, then use Object3D as a wrapper and then move that wrapper.

```
var wrapper = new THREE.Object3D();
wrapper.add(node0);
wrapper.add(node1);
wrapper.add(edge0);
scene.add(wrapper);
```

In this case you don't insert your meshes into scene directly, but rather whole wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try and make it work with this suggestion, and will keep you informed of the result.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this wrapper method creates a single object out of the 3 parts. So my question must have been poorly worded, sorry... What I try to do is, when moving a node, the edge will adjust itself between the moving node and the non-moving node - it may have to rotate (around the fixed node) and expand (to keep the connection between the fixed node and the moving one). Do I edit the main question, or is here OK?